# magento 1.9. update grand total in one step checkout page

Tags: php, magento, magento-1.9, subtotal, onestepcheckout

How i can update grand total in indexController method saveAddressOnestepcheckoutAction?
This not work:

```
Mage::helper('checkout/cart')->getQuote()->setSubtotal($subTotal);
```

It is clear that the value is overwritten, but how do I fix it? Thanks for any help

Comment: What controller? Where exactly You want update grant total and why?

Comment: IndexController in Onestepcheckout. I did the custom shipping price. Solved a problem, i edit function saveShipping.  thank you for answer.